# Merge video files using Concat filter in FFmpeg

Tags: android, ffmpeg, video-codecs

I am using FFmpeg to concat video files of different codecs in my android application.
I read the FFmpeg documentation and tried the following things.

`1. ffmpeg -i "concat:input1.mpg|input2.mpg" -c copy output.mp4` (works only for mpg files)

```
2. ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -c copy -bsf dump_extra 1.ts
   ffmpeg -i 2.mp4 -c copy -bsf dump_extra 2.ts
   ffmpeg -i "concat:1.ts|2.ts" -c copy output.mp4 (works for mp4 files)
```

I tried both the methods for 3gp files but it throws an error in stream filters.The second method stores the .ts files in device that should not be done and also i lost the quality of the video.

When i googled it out i found that FFmpeg provides a way to concat files with different codecs.So i tried the following command to this in a single step without storing files in device.

```
fmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.3gp -i 3.mpg -filter_complex '[0:0] [0:1] [1:0] [1:1]
 [2:0] [2:1] concat=n=3:v=1:a=1 [a] [v] ' -map '[a]' -map '[v]' -c copy output.mp4
```

It throws the following exception:

```
ffmpeg version 1.2.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jun 25 2013 20:34:51 with gcc 4.6 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
  configuration: 
  libavutil      52. 18.100 / 52. 18.100
  libavcodec     54. 92.100 / 54. 92.100
  libavformat    54. 63.104 / 54. 63.104
  libavdevice    54.  3.103 / 54.  3.103
  libavfilter     3. 42.103 /  3. 42.103
  libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
F.mp4: No such file or directory
tsk@tsk:~/Android/Backups/android-ffmpeg-x264/Project/jni$ ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -filter_complex '[0:1] [0:0] [1:1] [1:0] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]' -map '[v]' -map '[a]' output.mp4
ffmpeg version 1.2.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jun 25 2013 20:34:51 with gcc 4.6 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
  configuration: 
  libavutil      52. 18.100 / 52. 18.100
  libavcodec     54. 92.100 / 54. 92.100
  libavformat    54. 63.104 / 54. 63.104
  libavdevice    54.  3.103 / 54.  3.103
  libavfilter     3. 42.103 /  3. 42.103
  libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: mp41
    creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
  Duration: 00:00:04.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1457 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 1454 kb/s, SAR 349:320 DAR 349:240, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: mp41
    creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
  Duration: 00:00:04.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1498 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(und): Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 1495 kb/s, SAR 349:320 DAR 349:240, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Stream specifier ':1' in filtergraph description [0:1] [0:0] [1:1] [1:0] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a] matches no streams.
```

I googled out but found no solution yet.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to include the complete ffmpeg console output instead of just a selection.

Comment: @Lord i gave included the complete ffmpeg console.Pls have a look at it.

Comment: @vijay did you ever get this working? Running the same command to try concatenate 3 different formats, some with audio, some without.

Comment: Did you get this working?! Can you provide code for concatenation?